# How to explain "changing dependent variables feed into model impact will also changes" intuitively with plain English

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I need to explain regression model to people in other domain (most executives in company.) In their language, they care more about if certain variable make positive or negative impact on the response variable. So they can make the decision.

How can I explain intuitively, that if we add or remove variables, or adding interactions between variables, the sign of the coefficient can completely change?

Answer (score 1):

The questions in the title and in the body of your post seem to be different questions, but I think you mean to ask "How can I show that adding or removing IVs from a model, or adding an interaction term to a model, can change the sign of the coefficient of an IV you haven't touched?"

Well, how about an example? Let $X_1 = (1, -1, 2)$, $X_2 = (0, 1, 0)$, and $Y = X_1 + X_2$. Then regressing $Y$ on $X_2$ alone yields a coefficient of $-1.5$, but adding $X_1$ to the model changes the coefficient to $1$.